# Accuracy of derivatives as instant variation predictor

Tags: calculus, derivatives

For the following equation: $f(x)=4x^2 + 16x - 10$

`At x=1, y = 10`

`At x=2, y = 38`

Given the derivative is $f'(x)=8x + 16$ and so the instant variation at `x=1`, as calculated by the derivative, is `24`, I'd assume `f(2)` should be `10 + 24`, which is slightly below the actual value.

Please keep in mind that I'm not very good at calculus nor math in general, I'm just curious about it. This question is probably silly but I mean it.

Why is it not accurate? I'd like to know how reliable is the derivative as means of infering the next value on a continuous function given $U = Z $

Is it possible you'd get results far off the actual value when using derivatives or is it somehow always a close one?

For $U = Q$, is there a way to tell the exact variation on $x$ which yields the variation you got from the derivative? I mean, in the example above, the exact $\Delta x$ which produces $\Delta y=24$ when $x=1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivative
only predicts accurately
if the function is *linear*.

In this case,
the function is quadratic,
so the linear prediction
from the derivative
gets more and more inaccurate
as the line gets further
from the point.

You can see this
by looking at
the Taylor series
about the point.
For a quadratic like this,
$f(x+h)
=f(x)+hf'(x)+h^2f''(x)/2
$.

For
$f(x)=4x^2 + 16x - 10
$,
$f'(x)
= 8x+16
$
and
$f''(x)
=8
$,
so the error is
$h^2(8)/2
=4h^2
$.
For a step of 1
(from 1 to 2),
the error is
$4\cdot 1^2
= 4
$,
which is exactly what you got
(38-34 = 4).

Comment: Oh, ok. So there is a way to calculate the error of the derivative. I should have googled that. This is all I needed to know, thanks. I'll look into that. But maybe you could antecipate one thing: If I'm computing the derivative at a point while also computing the error through this method. Will I always get exact results or at some point even the error calculation could get inaccurate?

Comment: The error involves the second and higher derivatives. As the Taylor series shows, the error is generally proportional to the square of the distance from the point, so if you go twice as far, the error will be about four times as much.